# Split date into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to split each date and make a seperate sheet for it, im having a little trouble on selecting each day and pasting them into seperate worksheets. I decided to split up the date and time into seperate columns so it is easier for me to Visualize it.

Thank you for the help.

'how it looks now
[image]

how it should look after code is ran, dont mind column B and C being different as its just an example.
[image]

```
Sub CompareEachTime()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim Target As Range
  Dim results As Variant
  Dim x As Long
  Dim comp As Range
  Dim itter As Long
  Dim lastRow As Long

  Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
     'my array
     Set Target = .Range("A5:AR10", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
     results = Target.Value2

    'find last cell
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row

    itter = 1
    x = 1
    Do While itter < lastRow

    'compare date to see if it is equal comparing column B as it is date
    If (results(itter, 2) = results(itter + 1, 2)) Then

    itter = itter + 1

    Else
    'if different date copy the days and paste to new sheet
    'this is where I need help I think Select the date make new sheet then 
    'paste it to the new data sheet then go back to main sheet and do it 
    'till the end.

    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = results(itter, 2)

    Worksheets(results(itter, 2)).Activate
    results(itter, 2).Paste
    ws.Select

    x = itter + 1

    End If

    Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `results()` used for? Is this a function you created? Also, your line: `results(itter, 2).Paste` you are 'pasting' (again, not sure what `results()` is for) something, but I don't see where you ever copied it -- what all on the original sheet should be copied to the new sheet, and where on the new sheet?

Comment: Record a VBA macro (Alt + T, M, R) using autofilter to filter on date. This will give you the basis of a script where you copy the sheet with autofilter on.

Comment: @K.Davis I set results equal to target, amd im copying each days worth of data into a new sheet from the 1st cell to w.e it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is what I came up with, there were some errors with the methods you were using:

-your LastRow was ending up returning the first row

-your code seemed to slap down a new worksheet for every date checked

-the worksheet.add method can't be combined with the read/write property .name (*as far as I could figure)

I basically rewrote the looping structure to only add a new sheet if the dates didn't match.... sadly you can't name a worksheet with the "/" character :C so the sheet names are like 12272017 instead of 12/27/2017

*Also, you wanted to show the dates with the time? .numberformat can do that with the format:* "mm/dd/yyyy mm:ss"

```
Sub SortDat_toSheet()
Dim x, y, i, n As Long
Dim wsNam As String
Dim Target, TDate, TRange As Range
Dim Results As Variant
Dim Wks As Worksheet

Set Wks = ActiveSheet
Set Target = Range("A1:D31", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Results = Target.Value
Wks.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy  mm:ss"
n = 1             'set n to the column with the dates
x = UBound(Results, 1)
y = UBound(Results, 2)
Set TDate = Target(1, n)

For i = 1 To x
wsNam = Results(i, n)
wsNam = NamGen(wsNam)
If Not (i + 1) > x Then
    If Left(Results(i, n), 10) <> Left(Results(i + 1, n), 10) Then
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = wsNam
        Wks.Range(TDate.Address, Target(i, n)).Copy
        Sheets(wsNam).Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Columns(n).AutoFit
        Set TDate = Target(i + 1, n)
    End If
Else
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = wsNam
        Wks.Range(TDate.Address, Target(i, n)).Copy
        Sheets(wsNam).Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Columns(n).AutoFit
End If
Next i
Wks.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Function NamGen(BadNam As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim xChar As String
xChar = ""
For i = 1 To 10
    If Mid(BadNam, i, 1) Like "[1234567890]" Then
        xChar = xChar & Mid(BadNam, i, 1)
    End If
Next i
NamGen = xChar
End Function
```

Hope this helps! I'm kinda new to VBA so ;D

**So I imagine you also need the other columns transferred in to match the column of dates? I do a little trick for that(in VBA): make a index, match, match formula, set the .value of all the cells to that formula, it does all the work... then copy and paste the cells back as just values... it is fast n easy ;)